# How to use RIA Services QueryBuilder<T>

Tags: silverlight, ria, query-builder

According to the QueryBuilder’s parameter list, an EntityQuery of T object is a candidate for query shaping. However, my attempts to do so have been unsuccessful. I’m wondering if anyone knows how to use the ApplyTo method on an EntityQuery of T in order to filter it on the client?

This is what I have so far:

The following snippet succeeds in returning all custom entities stored within a particular database table.

```
var ctx = new CustomDomainContext();
var query = ctx.GetAllCustomEntitiesQuery();

var lo = ctx.Load<CustomEntity>(query);
lo.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    var result = lo.Entities.ToList();
};
```

The following snippet attempts to shape the query used above to delimit the results using the RIA Services QueryBuilder. Unfortunately, all of the data is still returned.

```
var ctx = new CustomDomainContext();
var query = ctx.GetAllCustomEntitiesQuery();

var builder = new QueryBuilder<CustomEntity>();
builder.Where(c => c.Id == 1);
builder.ApplyTo(query);

var lo = ctx.Load<CustomEntity>(query);
lo.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    var result = lo.Entities.ToList(); --> Still returns all entities!
};
```

No doubt I am using the QueryBuilder incorrectly. Has anyone had any experience in applying the QueryBuilder to an EntityQuery of T?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised my error. The QueryBuilder's ApplyTo method doesn't alter the orginal EntityQuery but instead returns a new one. Hence, all I needed to do was load the QueryBuilder's returned EntityQuery into the Load method of the DomainContext.

Answer (score 0):

```
lo.Completed += (s, e) => 
{     
    foreach(CustomEntity item in lo.Entities)
    {
      list.add(item);
    }
 };
```